# How to update a calculated field based on the value of a field in the same record

Tags: ms-access-2013

I am developing an app for an RPG. I need to track ability scores and a corresponding modifier. I was going to put this in one table and it would look like this:

Table (Ability Scores)
Field 1 = Strength
Field 2 = StrengthModifier

If strength is an 8 or 9; then StrengthModifier would be 1.
If strength is a 10, 11, or 12; then StrengthModifier would be 2.

How would I do this in Access?

Comment: Sounds like the record in `Score 1 Mod` should be linked to the record in `Score` and a query used to pull out the record in `Score 1 Mod` with the corresponding calculated value from `Score`.   Is there a reason why that approach wouldn't work in your program?

Comment: Your question is much too vague. Please [edit] it to let us know **what** the "corresponding value in `Score 1 Mod`" might possibly be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply make [StrengthModifier] a [calculated field](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-ca/article/Add-a-calculated-field-to-a-table-14a60733-2580-48c2-b402-6de54fafbde3?CorrelationId=da829814-91f3-4935-bc02-2fea51025f0c&ui=en-US&rs=en-CA&ad=CA) whose Expression is

```
IIf([Strength]>=8 And [Strength]<=9,1,IIf([Strength]>=10 And [Strength]<=12,2,Null))
```

and whose Return Type is `Long Integer`.

Comment: This is almost exactly what I was looking for. One other question. I need to do this for several ranges. Is there a way to accomplish the exact same thing, but through VBA?

Comment: You could just nest more `IIf()` statements, or if that got too messy you could also do something similar using a "real" numeric field for [StrengthMofidier] and have a Before Change [data macro](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/create-a-data-macro-HA010378170.aspx) update it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I think that you want this in at least four different tables. I won't assume to know what other data you're storing, just the data that's relevant to this question. Here's what I think they would look like.

[ER Diagram](http://www.pineboxsolutions.com/access/characters_scores.png)

You would then write a query to relate the characters to their ability scores and those modifiers

[Ability Query](http://www.pineboxsolutions.com/access/ability_query.png)